# Amazon S3: Upload files from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I have generated a pre-signed PUT URL using the aws-sdk. I then passed it to the front end, where I use a form control to upload a file. I parse the the pre-signed url to get the tokens like AWSAccessKeyId, Signature etc and create a JSON object called postData. I then use the Angular $http service to invoke a post request with the pre-signed URL. But, when I do this I get an 403 error from S3, saying that it is forbidden. I have enabled CORS on S3 and allowed GET, PUT and POST requests. Can anyone please help with a code snippet that needs to be used in Angular.

```
var postData = {
    AWSAccessKeyId: parms.AWSAccessKeyId[0],
    'x-amz-acl': parms['x-amz-acl'][0],
    Signature: parms.Signature[0],
    Expires: parms.Expires[0],
    'Content-Type': parms['Content-Type'][0],
    file: file,
    key: key
};
$http.post(preSignedPostUrl, postData)
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function(data) {

    });
```